# readv from Socket returns ENOENT

Tags: linux, sockets

What can be the reason for a Linux socket to set the error to ENOENT on readv() ?

The socket in question is non-blocking and runs on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: How is the socket being created?

Comment: Are you sure it's `readv` that last set `errno`?

Comment: seems an error related to readdir. Never seen on socket operation.

Comment: Is this a server process, so a lot of sockets are opened and closed, and there is a reasonable chance you're accessing one that has recently been closed, maybe by a parent process? I believe to remember that "recently used file descriptor" causes ENOENT in some syscalls. Or, as larsmans said: might not be readv at all, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errno` is only set when a system call returns -1. You should only read it after checking the return value of `readv`.